# Como saber se o código é JavaScript ou alguma derivação dele?

Tags: javascript

Estou com um código que segue a estrutura abaixo. Ele está em um arquivo ".js". A dúvidas é:

É um código javascript puro ou de alguma derivação dele? Se não, como faço para saber?

```
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');
const { Before } = require('cucumber');

// Synchronous
Before(function () {
  this.callSid = uuidv1();
  this.audioOrder = 0;
});
```

Comment: Aparentemente isso parece ser Cucumber, um framework ou ferramenta assim como outros (Selenium, Karma, Mocha, etc...) que resumidamente, são utilizados para a realização de testes de funcionalidades em códigos.

Comment: Mas essa estrutura em que ele importa 'cucumber' e utiliza o método Before eu sigo a codificação padrão do Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deve definir a linguagem pela sintaxe, lints e formato de arquivo, pois  o que definirá será sua aplicação, e como será compilado. caso seja em js, mesmo com uso de lints para corrigir erros de sintaxe diferenças entre es5 ou es6 e etc.

como esta usando const, importando o com o require esse modulo Before, e fato que esta usando es6(js)

[excelente artigo sobre es6](https://medium.com/@matheusml/o-guia-do-es6-tudo-que-voc%C3%AA-precisa-saber-8c287876325f)

exemplo de verificações:

`(fun [x] (+ (* 2 x)) qual linguagem ?`

apenas é possível saber a linguagem desse código caso o desenvolvedor tenha conhecimento sobre ou caso sua ide tenha alguma forma de verificação.

`let lista:Array<Produtos> = [...] qual linguagem ?`

ou

```
 List<Produto> produtos  = this.produtosService.obterTodos();
```

acredito que a forma mais fácil e usar um editor no estilo do vscode ou sublime que possuem diversas ferramentas para esse tipo de verificação.

Comment: Muito boa explanação, +1.